# MATLAB textfiles change several entries(numbers) between two strings

Tags: matlab

I have several GPS files and I want to merge them into a single file. Therefore I need to change one entry, since the all start with trace #1 again.

Here is an example of the text file:

> Trace #1 at position 0.000000
>   $GPGGA,092105.95,4635.2492567,N,00823.5402932,E,1,13,0.8,2355.019,M,,,,*00
>
> Trace #2 at position 1.000000
>   $GPLLQ,092106.10,042916,,,,,0,13,5.522,,*5D
>   $GPGGA,092106.20,4635.2492568,N,00823.5402891,E,1,13,0.8,2355.020,M,,,,*00
>
> Trace #1 at position 6.000000
>   $GPGGA,092106.70,4635.2492591,N,00823.5402862,E,1,13,0.8,2355.034,M,,,,*0A
>
> Trace #2 at position 7.000000
>   $GPGGA,092106.70,4635.2492591,N,00823.5402862,E,1,13,0.8,2355.034,M,,,,*0A
>
> Trace #3 at position 8.000000
>   $GPGGA,092106.70,4635.2492591,N,00823.5402862,E,1,13,0.8,2355.034,M,,,,*0A

My desired output should have every `Trace #` changed to be incremental (`Trace #1` to `Trace #5`). The position doesn’t has to be changed since it is not used for further processing.

In total I have around 18000 traces.

Comment: No I can copy them all into one textfile,  but have to change the trace id to a continous trace ID starting with 1 to N traces.

Answer (score 2):

While in principle it would be possible to correct the counters while merging all the files, I think for your case it's easier to use some post-processing after the final merge. I.e., first merge all files, and then correct the final file.

Below is my post-processing solution. In words:

1. read all text into memory
2. search for lines to be corrected
3. split those lines up into parts to keep and parts to correct
4. do corrections on the relevant parts
5. write everything to file.

Note that [`regexp`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) is slower and a bit harder to use than `strfind`, but it allows you to be much more flexible with formatting. Silly things like accidental leading spaces, different number of spaces, etc. between different output files don't affect the processing at all. Also, `regexp` allows you to do steps 2 and 3 in one call, altogether making it a lot faster and simpler than `strfind`.

Anyway, here goes:

```
% Read the file into memory
fid = fopen('GPS_data.txt', 'r');
    txt = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter','\n');
    txt = txt{1};
fclose(fid);

% Find relevant lines and separate into tokens
tok = regexp(txt, ...
             '^(\s*Trace\s*#\s*)(\d*)(.*)$',...
             'tokens');

% Do the replacements
matches = ~cellfun('isempty', tok);
txt(matches) = cellfun(@(x,y)[x{1}{1}  int2str(y)  x{1}{3}], ...     
                       tok(matches),...
                       num2cell(1:nnz(matches))',...
                       'UniformOutput', false);

% Write results to file                  
fid = fopen('GPS_data_corrected.txt', 'w');
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', txt{:});
fclose(fid);
```

Using `arrayfun` or plain loop allows you to get rid of the `num2cell`, but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `fileread` and [`strfind`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) as shown below. In my experience, `strfind` is easier to use than `regexp`.

```
%% Read file:
file_string = fileread('C:\Users\rfpe\Documents\MATLAB\GPS_data.txt');

%% Find indices where the word "Trace" starts
idx = [strfind(file_string, 'Trace'), numel(file_string)];

%% Find the indices where the phrase " at" starts
idx_2 = strfind(file_string, ' at');

%% Loop through the lines of the text, and add each line to
%% separate cells in new_txt
for n = 1:numel(idx)-1;
    new_txt{n} = sprintf('%s%i%s', file_string(idx(n):idx(n)+6), ...
    n, file_string((idx_2(n)):idx(n+1)-1));
end

%% Open new txt file, with writing rights
fileID = fopen('GPS_data_new.txt','w');

%% Print each cell element into the new text file using fprintf
fprintf(fileID,'%s', new_txt{:});

%% Close the open file:
fclose(fileID);
```

---

It outputs the following, for a file with 11 Traces:

```
Trace #1 at position 0.000000 
$GPGGA,092105.95,4635.2492567,N,00823.5402932,E,1,13,0.8,2355.019,M,,,,*00

Trace #2 at position 1.000000 $GPLLQ,092106.10,042916,,,,,0,13,5.522,,*5D 
$GPGGA,092106.20,4635.2492568,N,00823.5402891,E,1,13,0.8,2355.020,M,,,,*00

Trace #3 at position 6.000000 
$GPGGA,092106.70,4635.2492591,N,00823.5402862,E,1,13,0.8,2355.034,M,,,,*0A

Trace #4 at position 7.000000 
$GPGGA,092106.70,4635.2492591,N,00823.5402862,E,1,13,0.8,2355.034,M,,,,*0A

Trace #5 at position 8.000000 
$GPGGA,092106.70,4635.2492591,N,00823.5402862,E,1,13,0.8,2355.034,M,,,,*0A

Trace #6 at position 0.000000 
$GPGGA,092105.95,4635.2492567,N,00823.5402932,E,1,13,0.8,2355.019,M,,,,*00

Trace #7 at position 1.000000 $GPLLQ,092106.10,042916,,,,,0,13,5.522,,*5D 
$GPGGA,092106.20,4635.2492568,N,00823.5402891,E,1,13,0.8,2355.020,M,,,,*00

Trace #8 at position 6.000000 
$GPGGA,092106.70,4635.2492591,N,00823.5402862,E,1,13,0.8,2355.034,M,,,,*0A

Trace #9 at position 7.000000 
$GPGGA,092106.70,4635.2492591,N,00823.5402862,E,1,13,0.8,2355.034,M,,,,*0A

Trace #10 at position 8.000000 
$GPGGA,092106.70,4635.2492591,N,00823.5402862,E,1,13,0.8,2355.034,M,,,,*0A

Trace #11 at position 0.000000 
$GPGGA,092105.95,4635.2492567,N,00823.5402932,E,1,13,0.8,2355.019,M,,,,*00
```